# Prove there is at most one subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_q$ and find intersection of two subfields

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let G be any field 
>  a)Prove that for any primary $q, G$ contains
>   at most one subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_q$ 
>  b) If
>   $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ are subfields of $G$, prove
>   that $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}\bigcap \mathbb{F}_{p^n} = \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$
>   where $d=gcd(m,n)$

Here are my attempts:
a) I know that a field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ has a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ iff $m|n$ so in the case of $G$ being finite if $G=\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ it will have a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_q$.  If $G$ is finite and of another form it will not contain a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_q$.  Not sure about what to do if $G$ is infinite (if we even need to look at that is unclear since the name of this section is finite fields) or if this is even right
b) $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ are subfields of $G$ so that means $G = \mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ for some $k$ and $m|k$ and $n|k$ so $gcd(m,n)|k$.  Not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a), it looks like you're trying to prove existence whereas the question only asks for uniqueness assuming existence. As a hint, consider the polynomial $f=x^q-x\in\mathbb{F}_q[x]$.

For b), you're assuming that $G$ is finite, which is unnecessary. Instead, notice that $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}\cap\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ will be a subfield of both $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Try to use the fact you stated about existence of subfields of finite fields and what you proved in a) to show that $|L|=gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: How does that polynomial help for a?

Comment: Have you seen that every element of $\mathbb{F}_q $ is a root of $x^q-x$? This is because, as Tomasz mentioned, the Frobenius automorphism has order $n$ where $q=p^n$. Then just ask the question "how many roots can a polynomial over a field possibly have?"

Comment: It could have $q$ roots? so how does that say its unique

Comment: It can have at most $q$ roots. Also, we know that every  element of a subfield of size $q $ must be a root. At this point you should be able to make cardinality arguments to show that the set of roots of $x^q-x$ is in fact the only subfield of order $q $ (at least if a subfield of order $q$ exists at all)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: if $K,L$ are finite subfields of $G$, then they generate a finite subfield of $G$.

Alternative **Hint**: the field $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ is fixed by the $n$-th power of the Frobenius automorphism (but no smaller power).